Sitecore Forms Default --select-- option in dropdown
I'm working on Sitecore Forms XP10.3 and need to implement dropdown functionality. I have created a dynamic data source for the dropdown, but I also need to include a default option, such as "--Choose--." However, there is no out-of-the-box option for this in Sitecore. Could you suggest how to implement the default option functionality?
Is there any custom implementation? Kindly suggest.

Please specify the Sitecore Version or is it for XM Cloud Forms/

@Sreekrishnan i have updated the details
